# Is there any way to find the URL that you are currently scraping?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently trying to create a spider which crawls each result and takes some info from each of them. The only problem is that I don't know how to find the URL that I'm currently on (I need to retrieve that too).

Is there any way to do that?

I know how to do that using Selenium and Scrapy-Selenium, but I'm only using a simple CrawlSpider for this project.

Comment: current_url = response.request.url

Comment: @UserOne can you add that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`current_url = response.request.url`